# Deleting the dual partitioned Ubuntu

Tags: boot, partitioning, windows-7

I have had Ubuntu and Windows 7 dual partitioned for some time now but need the extra space on my computer. I have two questions:

1. When I went into the run window and deleted the two partitions containing Ubuntu the space was labeled "free space" and highlighted green. Is this space available to use on my windows 7 partition or is this another way to say "unallocated"?
2. I am having trouble with booting my computer even after booting from a disk. I went to "repair computer" and I also tried the two commands "bootrec /fixboot" and "bootrec /fixmbr" but my computer still will not boot. My computer says "BOOTMGR is missing".

How do I fix my second problem and an answer to the first question would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: 1. That free space you can use in windows.  2. What message your getting after using bootrec/fixmbr and bootrec/fixboot.

Comment: It's what comes up on the screen when I try to restart. It asks me if I'd like to boot from cd and when I don't push any keys it says the BOOTMGR is missing. I am seeing online that the fix is to boot from the cd and select "repair computer" but it doesn't work, I keep getting the same message.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to remove Ubuntu and put Windows back on?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/133533/how-to-remove-ubuntu-and-put-windows-back-on)

Comment: After booting into windows cd and selecting repair using cmd and entering the commands what message are you getting in the cmd (you should see successful msg if not what msg your getting)

Comment: I am getting the successful message. I think the Windows 7 OS I have on the cd doesn't correspond to my computer. I think I'm trying to use a 32 bit system when I need a 64. Could this be the issue?